# Jquery conflict between two functions

Tags: jquery, conflict

I have two functions, which both hide different form elements, the problem is they seem to be conflicting with one another.

I have add a no conflict line to my code, but I am new to Jquery and not sure if I am going about this correctly.

Please find below my code.

```
 $.noConflict();
 $(function(){     
 $('RadioGroup1').click(function(){
 if ($(this).attr("id") == "realtime")
 {
  $('#total2').show();
 } else {
  $("#total2").hide();
 }
 });
 });


 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#contact-location').change(function(){
    var location = $(this).val(),
    div = $('#' + location);

    $('div').hide();
        div.show();

});
});
```

Comment: in jQuery you select your elements almost like in CSS. check it out here [Borrowing from CSS 1–3, and then adding its own, jQuery offers a powerful set of tools for matching a set of elements in a document](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose "RadioGroup1" is the name of your radio buttons.

Then, your first event handler should be defined like this :

```
$('[name=RadioGroup1]').click(function(){
 if (this.id === "realtime") {
   $('#total2').show();
  } else {
   $("#total2").hide();
  }
});
```